# Framer-notion not fading out when only one component is rendered instead of the initial 3

Tags: html, css, reactjs, framer-motion, react-tsx

I have this service component:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Service(props) {
  return (
    <div className="feature-container">
      <div className={`feature-box-1 ${props.className}`}>
        <div className="icon">
          <i className={props.imageName}></i>
        </div>
        <div className="feature-content">
          <h5>{props.name}</h5>
          <p>{props.desc}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here I save two states:

```
 const [selectedServiceIndex, setSelectedServiceIndex] = useState(null);

  const [isServiceSelected, setIsServiceSelected] = useState(false);

  const handleServiceClick = (index) => {
console.log("Clicked service index:", index); // Add a log to track the index clicked

if (index >= 0 && index < services_data.length) {
  // Check if index is within range
  if (isServiceSelected && selectedServiceIndex === index) {
    setIsServiceSelected(false); // If already selected, deselect
    console.log(false);
    setSelectedServiceIndex(null);
  } else {
    setSelectedServiceIndex(index);
    setIsServiceSelected(true); // Select the service
    console.log(true);
  }
} else {
  console.error("Invalid index or index out of range");
}
```

};

Initially, SelectedServiceIndex will be null, which will render all services, as described below:

```
{selectedServiceIndex !== null ? (
                      <AnimatePresence>
                        <motion.div
                          initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
                          animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
                          exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
                          transition={{ duration: 2 }}
                          className="service-wrapper"
                          key={selectedServiceIndex}
                          onClick={() => handleServiceClick(null)}
                        >
                          <Service
                            name={services_data[selectedServiceIndex].name}
                            imageName={
                              services_data[selectedServiceIndex].imageName
                            }
                            className={
                              services_data[selectedServiceIndex].className
                            }
                            desc={services_data[selectedServiceIndex].desc}
                          />
                        </motion.div>
                      </AnimatePresence>
                    ) : (
                      <>
                        {services_data.map((item, index) => (
                          <motion.div
                            initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
                            animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
                            exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
                            transition={{ duration: 2 }}
                            className={`service-wrapper fade-services-in`}
                            onClick={() => handleServiceClick(index)}
                            key={index}
                          >
                            <Service
                              name={item.name}
                              imageName={item.imageName}
                              className={item.className}
                              desc={item.desc}
                            />
                          </motion.div>
                        ))}
                      </>
                    )}
```

My problem is regarding fading out when an element is removed,from my understanding the exit condition on framer-motion.motion gets executed when something is removed from the dome, but how do you accomplish that?

In my case, initially on the dome are 3 service components, after clicking on any of them, i'll render just that one, but do I really remove anything from the DOM, I assume no, so no, I m just serving a different version of it?

Now how, on earth do i go about removing any other service from the dom that has index different from selectedServiceIndex, I m stuck on this for hours now, maybe you guys have an idea that i can work with?

Working example at [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/itsMGA/eliptum-react/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522GIT%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr4yyoke00062a66axztbvo3%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B74.8585286961439%252C25.141471303856093%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr4yyoke00022a66agxnvbqa%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr4yyoke00042a66vyfnurjh%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr4yyoke00052a66n9s5auhu%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B43.769855121784666%252C56.230144878215334%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clr4yyoke00022a66agxnvbqa%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr4yyoke00022a66agxnvbqa%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clr4yyoke00052a66n9s5auhu%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr4yyoke00052a66n9s5auhu%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6pq1nz060x2a66vwr61gcw%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2523%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr6pq1nz060x2a66vwr61gcw%2522%257D%252C%2522clr4yyoke00042a66vyfnurjh%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr4yyoke00042a66vyfnurjh%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr6ppu5s05xa2a669i71ei50%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6ppu5s05xa2a669i71ei50%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522npm%2520install%2520framer-motion%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr7vfan2009u2a67xh84gft9%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)